# Converting a global system to an organization-based system in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, activerecord

I have a system which consists of `User`,`Title`,`TitleType`,`Region` and `RegionType` entities/models. The relationship of the entities are as follows:

> Title -> {user_id, title_type_id, region_id}
>
> TitleType -> {region_type_id}
>
> Region -> {region_type_id}

Now, I have to add `Organization` entity to system so that `Title`, `TitleType`, `Region`, and `RegionType` entities should be related to organizations. Admins of organizations should create Titles, TitleTypes, Regions and RegionTypes. Therefore my first intention is to alter the relationship into:

> Title -> {user_id, title_type_id, region_id, **organization_id**}
>
> TitleType -> {title_type_id, **organization_id**}
>
> Region -> {region_type_id, **organization_id**}
>
> **RegionType -> {organization_id}**

Is this the best solution for my case? There are lots of organization ids and they make harder to work. I don't know which concept is this, and no idea if there is a better solution for the case. I'm using ruby on rails and postgresql as db. Is there any better way that I could do for this problem?

**Note**: The regions, region_types, title_types and titles are for organizations. An organization can create regions, region_types, title_types and titles. Regions are not global they belong to organizations.

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you are trying to do here, can you explain a bit more about what the application is supposed to do?

Comment: It's like a community application. Where users can have titles. First. the titles were given by us. However, we decided to add organizations to system and we wanted them to add titles to users. They can broadcast messages to all their members. Membership is established by Title. Organizations may send messages to only certain titletypes etc.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to add organization ids to all of the other tables. If I understand correctly, Organizations only *own* TitleTypes. So the only table that needs changing is TitleTypes.

So:

*Users* have *Titles*

*Titles* have a *TitleType* (belongs_to)

Each *TitleType* belongs to an *Organization*

Titles themselves do not need an organization id, they belong to a title type, which belongs to an organization. The same is true of regions. If region types belong to organizations, then regions do not need organization_ids, since they belong to region types.

Comment: Organizations can create Regions and RegionTypes, too :(

Comment: Are those regions restricted to those organizations? I thought they referred to 'real-world' regions.

Comment: Yes, they are the regions of organizations. That's why i put organization_ids to them. I guess what I want is some kind of branches in the database.

Comment: Adding an organization_id implies ownership, as in that organization is the only one who can use/access it. A good rule of thumb is that if the regions should be *deleted* when the organization is itself deleted then that means the organization owns them

Comment: Yes all the belongings of oganizations will be deleted when organization is deleted. Only users will stay on the system. A user can be in zero or many organizations.

Comment: I see your afford but it makes retrievel requests to be more complex. Thank you for your answers. I guess my initial idea is still best for me.

Comment: Read up a bit on database normalization. There are good reasons why I suggested you organize your data in that way. I know it seems that it will make your life harder now, but it may improve the maintainability of your database in the long term.